# Python findall() RE

Tags: python-3.x, findall

I am trying to find image files in a css file using Python re find all. The following works except it only finds the first image in the CSS file and ignores the rest. How do I make it to grab all image links?

img_links_in_css = re.findall('^.*(url|URL|Url|uRL|uRl)\s*(\s*(.+.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|svg))\s*).*?$', str(css))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your expression:

- The `.+` and `.*` tokens (wich are [greedy quantifiers](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap)) makes the RegEx match the first occurence and then capture all remaining characters of the string (especially if the CSS is minified); and
- The tokens `^` and `$` will only if the CSS isn't minified (all in one line) and if you use the *multi-line* flag (`re.M`or `re.MULTILINE`);

So, you could change it to (for non-minified CSS):

```
    pattern = r'^.+(?:uRl|URL|Url|uRL|Uri)\s?(\s*(?:.+.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg|svg))\s*).*?$'
    re.findall(pattern, str(css), re.M)
```

To work with minified CSS you have to eliminate the `.+` and `.*` tokens as well. A simplier expression can be used for this:

```
pattern = r'url\s*\(([^)]+)'
re.findall(pattern, str(css), re.I)
```

Where:

- `url\*`: matches any combination of the letters U, R and L, modified by the `re.I` flag to ignore cases. (`[Uu][Rr][Ll]` could be used instead);
- `\s*`: preceding or not by whitespaces;
- `\(`: an open parentheses;
- And finnaly, the group `([^)]+)` matching any character different than `)`.

**Example:**

```
    >>> css = 'body{background-attachment:fixed;background-image:uRl(./Images/bg4.png)}.img-default{background-image:Url(./images/def.jpg)}div#header{\nbackground-image:url(images/header-background.jpg)\n}'
    >>> re.findall(r'url\(([^)]+)', css, re.I)
    ['./Images/bg4.png', './images/def.jpg', 'images/header-background.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

in your regex `^` matches the start of a new line (or the entire file) and `$` matches the end. Therefor your regex matches the entire file (because of the `.*` at the end) and you have only one (non-overlapping) match.

Instead you should search for the following:

```
r'(url|URL|Url|uRL|uRl)\s(\s*(.+?\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|svg))\s*)'
```

The changes are

- removing `^.*` and `.*$` at beginning and end.
- `.+?` instead of `.+` for making int non-ambiguous (matching the smallest possible string)
- searching for an actual "." should be done with `\.` or `[.]`
- Note that the `\s*` is not necessary and that `\s\s*` can be replaced with `\s+` if it's not a matter of capturing-groups.

Also take care of what groups you want. Each `(...)` is a group that can be accessed for non-capturing groups use `(?:...)`.

Maybe like this (depending of which parts you want):

```
r'(?:url|URL|Url|uRL|uRl)\s\s*.+?\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg|svg)'
```

or

```
r'(?:url|URL|Url|uRL|uRl)\s\s*(.+?)\.(?:png|jpg|gif|jpeg|svg)'
```

for capturing only the part inside (in Python these capturing-groups are accessed with `\g<1>` if you need to process them).